# WinAppDriver/Appium error on Azure Pipelines when launching application

Tags: appium, winappdriver

We are attempting to move our WinAppdrvier/Appium test suite from self hosted to using MS hosted vms on Azure Pipelines (vmImage: windows-latest)

When we attempt to create the session we have a 500 server error with

```
{
  "status": 13,
  "value": {
    "error": "unknown error",
    "message": "An unknown error occurred in the remote end while processing the command."
  }
}
```

The ADO logs show the following:

```
POST /session HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, image/png
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 188
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Host: 127.0.0.1:4723
User-Agent: selenium/3.141.0 (.net windows)
{"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App","deviceName":"WindowsPC","platformName":"Windows"},"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"platformName":"Windows"}]}}
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Error
Content-Length: 133
Content-Type: application/json
{"status":13,"value":{"error":"unknown error","message":"An unknown error occurred in the remote end while processing the command."}}
```

This code below works when executed locally and on our self-hosted machines.

```cs
// Start WinAppDriver
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo { FileName = WinAppDriverPath };
_driverProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);

// Removed for brevity. Check that wait for WinAppdriver to start and that it is responding

// Launch application
var options = new AppiumOptions();
options.AddAdditionalCapability("app", "Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App");
options.AddAdditionalCapability("deviceName", "WindowsPC");
_session = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri(WinAppDriverUrl), options);
```

We have also tried starting winAppDriver with verb='RunAs'

What do we need to do to get our test running on Azure Pipelines?

Answer (score 0):

Use WinAppDriver task to start\stop WinAppDriver: [https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/modern-work-app-consult-blog/ui-testing-for-windows-apps-with-winappdriver-and-appium-azure/ba-p/829173#:~:text=Perform%20the%20UI%20tests](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/modern-work-app-consult-blog/ui-testing-for-windows-apps-with-winappdriver-and-appium-azure/ba-p/829173#:%7E:text=Perform%20the%20UI%20tests)